# Windows 7, 64bit TortoiseSVN-1.6.12, cannot commit

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

we have a Windows server running VisualSVN.

A coworker recently upgraded to Windows 7,  and is running `TortoiseSVN-1.6.12` 64-bit in Windows 7 64-bit, and can check projects out but cannot commit.

He gets the following error:

```
Commit failed:
access to '/svn/the_repo/!svn/act/b7929<some really long id>' forbidden
```

can anyone tell me how to fix this? As far we know, he has correct permissions and username/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your repository URL is correct. It is case sensitive, so

```
https://server/svn/Project/trunk
```

will generate your access error if the path is

```
https://server/svn/PROJECT/trunk
```

If it is wrong you can use "Relocate" under "TortoiseSVN" menu in Explorer to correct it.

Comment: Thanks, the VisualSVN support guys also reached the same conclusions which fixed the issue. It's weird, if you use the wrong case in the url it still let's you browse and check out from the repo but only presents problems when checking in.